# How to make two divs share the same scrollbar without wrapping them in a common container div?

Tags: html, css

I have 4 `div`s and I want the middle two `div`s to share the same scrollbar.

```
<div id="a">
    <p>A</p>
</div>

<div id="b">
    <p>B</p>
</div>

<div id="c">
    <p>C</p>
</div>

<div id="d">
    <p>D</p>
</div>
```

The below CSS would create two scrollbars for each of the `div`s

```
#b, #c {
    overflow-y : scroll;
}
```

Also I cannot put a wrapper container `div` around `div` b and `div` c and make that scrollable. I would want to achieve this with CSS only.

Comment: It seems a bit weird to want a "joined" scrollbar while also not joining the elements in a single container. If they are not in a single container, how can a browser properly scroll across both of them? Is there a valid use case for this?

Comment: With use case, I mean a use case in which a simple wrapping `<div>` element is not a possible solution.

Comment: @Flater the html code is generated by a custom framework, and it is does not allow wrapping as of now.. so I would need a CSS only work around..

Comment: What is stopping you from dynamically wrapping the elements after they have been rendered by your framework? A simple javascript script could do that for you. The only reason to not do that would be if your framework also includes frontend javascript (that still uses these elements and expects to find them where they were rendered). But if that is the case, then you maybe should not be messing with the rendered output of the framework at all, since those elements are still in use and the framework can't deal with you shuffling them around.

Comment: yes.. (that still uses these elements and expects to find them where they were rendered) that's the exact reason..